# Não consigo criar projeto usando Express Node.js

Tags: node.js

Estou seguindo um tutorial de `Node.js` e estou aprendendo sobre frameworks, porém quando vou tentar instalar o express pelo `cmd` da erro, eu estou tentando fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
express aplicativo1
```

E o erro que aparece no cmd é esse:

> 'express' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
>       ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Comment: Você [instalou o express pelo npm](http://expressjs.com/starter/installing.html) antes?

Comment: Sim, dessa forma: `npm install express`

Comment: Como está o teu `package.json`?

Comment: Já fizeste `require` do `express`?

Comment: Deu certo, na versão mais recente a instalação tem que ser feita dessa forma: `npm install express-generator -g`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Parece-me que você está chamando de 'express' dois pacotes diferentes:

1. `express` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) e
2. `express-generator` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator)

O primeiro é um web framework e o segundo é usado apenas para criar uma estrutura de diretórios para o web framework `express`.

Observe também que a opção -g do npm serve para instalar os pacotes de forma global no seu sistema operacional, o que, em geral, faz com que os comandos disponibilizados pelo pacote fiquem na PATH do sistema e possam ser acessados diretamente no terminal de comandos.

Assim, o erro que você obteve:

> 'express' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Ocorreu porque o seu sistema operacional não encontrou o comando 'express' em sua PATH, devido ao fato de que o pacote `express` não possui um comando 'express', mesmo que seja instalado de forma global. Quem possui esse comando é o pacote `express-generator` e, para poder usar esse comando a partir de qualquer diretório, é necessário que esse pacote seja instalado de forma global, usando a opção -g do npm.

Espero ter ajudado a esclarer um pouco mais sua dúvida e que continue estudando e aprendendo mais sobre Node.js

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Por nada! Estamos aqui para nos ajudarmos. Espero que continue desenvolvendo em Node.js

Comment: Opa, pode deixar vou continuar sim, estou "Apaixonado" pela linguagem